# General UML datatypes in visio not language specific?

Tags: java, uml, visio

When making a UML Classdiagram in Visio. it's only giving C#,C,VB Datatypes. how can I add datatypes or change this so it is not language specific because I want to make a diagram for a JAVA application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution that works for **Visio 2010** and should work for the newer versions.

You can make up your own package and data types.

1. First go to the Model Explorer tab on the left.
2. Then right-clicked on IDL Data Types and click Duplicate (since you don’t want to make it from scratch and it pretty much has what you should want).
3. It will then make a new package called "Package 1". Right-click on it and select Rename; something like “Java Data Types” since that is what you are making, but you can name it anything if you want.
4. Then open the new package and right-click each data type, one at a time, and select Properties.
5. Then it will open up the UML Property Editor. From there, click on Name, then remove the word “idl” from inside the brackets, so “boolean(idl)” now says ”boolean()”.

Now, one other thing: There is no int data type, so you need to make one. It is pretty easy;

1. Just right-click on your newly created folder, click New, then click Data Type. It should open the UML Datatypes Properties window.
2. Now, click inside the Name tab, type in “int()”, then click OK. And you’re all done.